# ToggleClass "no-scroll" causing body to stretch to amount of scrollbar's width

Tags: jquery, overlay

Currently I have an overlay sidebar that is initiated through a click. Once clicked, it will also add `no-scroll` class to body to prevent body from scrolling, and is controlled with `overflow:hidden` via CSS.

I tried:

```
$('.toggle-menu').click(function() {
    $('.sidebar-outer').toggleClass('open');
    $('body').toggleClass('no-scroll');
});
```

And here's the CSS:

```
body.no-scroll {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The overlay sidebar is working just fine and so with its css. My problem is, once toggle is clicked, body is stretched, takes the width of scroll-bar.

What to do to prevent body from scrolling without causing it to stretch?

Comment: @M0ns1f Do you even read?

Comment: sorry but , now i know the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jquery you can calculate the `scroll bar width`  then give that result as `body right margin` see example :

```js
var menuwidth = $('.toggle-menu').innerWidth();
var menunoscrollwidth = $('.toggle-menu')[0]['clientWidth'];


$('.toggle-menu').click(function() {
    var scrollwidh =menuwidth - menunoscrollwidth;
    alert(scrollwidh +' '+menuwidth+' '+menunoscrollwidth);
    $('.sidebar-outer').toggleClass('open');
    if($('body').hasClass('no-scroll')){
      $('body').css('margin-right',0);
    }else{$('body').css('margin-right',scrollwidh);}
    $('body').toggleClass('no-scroll');
    
});
```

```css
body
{
  background-color:blue;
  margin:0px;
}
.container
{
width:100%;
background-color:#ccc
}
div.toggle-menu {
  width:200px;
  height:900px;
  overflow:scroll;
}
div p {
  
    height:1200px;
}
body.no-scroll {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="toggle-menu">
<p>This is the scrolled div .........</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you. I modified the code a bit and using the following variable instead: `var scrollWidth= window.innerWidth-$(document).width();`. One more issue, margin-right is still there even after closing the toggle.

Comment: @Biyan see answer, i have added an if to check if the class no-scroll is on body else remove the margin, and mark it as an answer and give it an upvote : )

Comment: Perfect. My reputation is below 15, I can't give vote. But thank you so much for the help.